# Update date in a flutter application

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

i want to create a flutter application that contain a session of questions and this session (punch of questions) is generated online to the application.

on of these methods is to create my own API but i am asking is firebase can help me in this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, given your requirement Firebase is a bit of an overkill. But if you want to extend this functionality to include Social logins (google, facebook, etc;) and maybe realtime game experience, Firebase is definitely the place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an API in order to make request from your flutter app.
Firebase can help you to achieve what you are trying to do.
I recommend you to take a look at firestore (noSQL database), cloud functions(serverless functions), authentication with oAuth.